# How can I retrieve _POST data from a form created with a foreach loop?

Tags: php, post, foreach

I have an associative array of 20 names in this format:

```
$operationCodeName = array(
    "Overlord" => 44,
    "Rolling Thunder" => 68,
    "Desert Storm" => 91,
    "Phantom Fury" => 04,
...);
```

...and used the following foreach loop to generate a table (nested in a form) that displays each name and an integer year:

```
foreach($operationCodeName as $operation => $year) {
    echo "<tr>
          <td>" . $operation . "</td>
          <td align='center'>" . $year . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input name='comment" . $operation . "' size='50' type='text' placeholder='Comment here'></td>
    </tr>";
    }
```

I named the variables by concatenating the word 'comment' with the `$operation` variable in the name attribute of the text input.

*This part is working properly, although if there's a smarter way to do this, I'm all ears!*

When the user clicks the 'Submit' button, I need those comments to be displayed on a summary page. The table should display the same `$operation` and `$year` array elements just as on the first page, but then display the user's comments from that previous page.

I tried using a two-part solution to solve the problem:

First, my idea was to use the previous associative array to create each concatenated variable, use it to call the _POST method:

```
foreach($operationCodeName as $key => $value){
    ${"comment" . $key} = $_POST[${"comment" . $key}];
}
```

...and then loop through each in the comment column by echoing the concatenated variable, just as I had done to set them on the previous page in the third column:

```
foreach($operationCodeName as $operation => $year) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>" . $operation . "</td>
                <td align='center'>" . $year . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . ${"comment" . $operation} . "</td>
            </tr>";
    }
```

When I run this code, the table displays the first two columns correctly but generates empty `<td></td>` tags for the third column. `var_dump(_$POST);` displays:

```
array(21) { ["commentOverlord"]=> string(9) "Comment 1" ...
```

"Comment 1" was the comment entered in the previous page, so the data is here and I'm just not properly calling it for display in the table... That's actually encouraging!

I am assuming that I'm not properly declaring the variables, but I'm not sure where my miscommunication is happening.

How can I properly retrieve the comments from the first page, and display them in the third column of this dynamically generated table?

*Thanks for any and all suggestions! While I've been programming with Java for about a year, I've only been using PHP for about 2 weeks. That said, please forgive me for any rookie mistakes!*

Comment: Please provide data structure of array you are referring to.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` to see if it contains the keys and values that you expect

Comment: @EternalHour, it's an associative array in this format:
$operationCodeName = array(
    "Overlord" => 44,
    "Rolling Thunder" => 68,
    "Desert Storm" => 91, ...);

Comment: I meant add it to your question so we know what your data looks like.

Comment: @PatrickQ, the var_dump displays the concatenated variables exactly as I'd expected, but is is associating to "string(0)" like this:  array(21) { ["commentOverlord"]=> string(9) "Comment 1"...  The most interesting part of this to me is that "Comment 1" is exactly the comment that I'd input on the previous page. The data is here, I'm just not displaying it correctly... This is encouraging!

Comment: @Dave As EternalHour said, please _update your question_ with relevant information.  As you can see, it is quite hard to read code and output in comments.

Comment: I apologize and have updated my question! I appreciate both of your help with this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code above, you tried to create dynamic variables for each of the comment. That's not how dynamic variables can be created. You already have the data in POST request in array form so you can access each comment by the key you have created in the form comment concatenated with operationCode number. Try this!

```
foreach($operationCodeName as $operation => $year) {
        // replace space in operation key with _
        $operation = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $operation);
        $commentKey = "comment" . $operation;
        $comment = $_POST[$commentKey];
        echo "<tr>
                <td>" . $operation . "</td>
                <td align='center'>" . $year . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $comment . "</td>
            </tr>";
}
```

Comment: That did it!! Thank you so much! I tried to upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation points for it to post publicly.

Comment: it's OK. Glad that it helped.

Comment: The only issue now is that PHP automatically replaced spaces in the array $key value with underscores, so "Rolling Thunder" became "Rolling_Thunder." Those comments still are not displaying, but I think that I can figure that out! Thanks again!!

Comment: BOOM!!! I had just tried to use str_replace(' ', '_', $operation); but it didn't work. I'll have to read up on preg_replace. Thanks so much for all of your help!!